# How to overload stream operators to work with functions located in different files?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am trying to make a template `max` function (finds the biggest of three of something) to work with a class I have created.

Therefor I should overload the `>` operator and if I want to display the result of the `max` function I should also overload the `<<` operator.

If I create the class in another `.h` file and then overload the `<<` operator the program doesn't seem to recognize that the `<<` is overloaded.

```
template <typename X> X max(X a, X b, X c)
{
X maxNum = a;

if( b > maxNum )
    maxNum = b;
if( c > maxNum )
    maxNum = c;

return maxNum;
}
```

The class is in a separate `.h` file.

```
class Person
{
private:
    std::string Name;
    int Height;
    bool Gender;

public:
    Person() :Name(""), Height(0), Gender(false) {};
    Person(std::string Name, int Height, bool Gender) : Name(Name), 
    Height(Height), Gender(Gender) {};

    void SetName(std::string Name) { this->Name = Name; }
    void SetHeight(int Height) { this->Height = Height; }
    void SetGender(bool Gender) { this->Gender = Gender; }

    std::string GetName() { return Name; }
    int GetHeight() { return Height; }
    bool GetGender() { return Gender; }
};

std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream &MyStream, Person &a)
{
    MyStream << "Name: " << a.GetName() << ", Height: " << a.GetHeight() 
<< ", Gender: " << a.GetGender() << std::endl;
    return MyStream;
}
```

The main function is located in the same file as the `max` method (not the same as the class):

```
int main()
{
    Person a("Bob", 207, true), b("Alice", 367, false), c("Mickey", 107, 
    true);

    std::cout << max(a,b,c) <<  std::endl;
}
```

The error I get is:

```
Error   C2679   binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand 
operand of type 'X' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Error (active)  E0349   no operator "<<" matches these operands
```

However if I put everything in a single file it works just fine.

I would like to know why this happens and if there is a way around it.

Comment: `std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream &MyStream, Person &a)` should be `std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream &MyStream, const Person &a)`

Comment: Well it worked but I do not understand why it did. Thank you

Comment: Since you haven't shown us, I can only guess, but it's likely you're doing `cout << max(...)`, meaning you're trying to pass a temporary as a `Person&` (where a non-const reference is specifically for modifying the original argument, so it doesn't make much sense to compile).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put a forward declaration of your operator overload in the `Person` header file as well, to have the compiler recognizing it:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, Person&);
```

Also the signature of the overloaded operator should be

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Person&);
```

and getter / comparator functions accordingly

```
    std::string GetName() const { return Name; }
    int GetHeight() const { return Height; }
    bool GetGender() const { return Gender; }

    bool operator > (const Person&) const;
```

All of the `const` stuff is necessary to allow the compiler having these functions (which aren't intended to change the `Person` instance passed) to be applied for *rvalues* (e.g. results of expressions or temporary instances).

Comment: I already did it and it worked. However can you explain why this is needed?

Comment: @Valgrim It's needed to let the compiler resolve the overloaded functions for rvalues as are e.g. results of an expression.